# Guardar Informacion en base de datos

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy teniendo un problema al guardar información el la base de datos, pues quiero guardar el total, y lo que hace es guardarme la primera fila en donde deberia guardar el total. Tengo esta tabla que es donde lleno información.

```
<table id="insercion">
                                    <thead>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>INVENTARIO</td>
                                        <td>PRODUCCION</td>
                                        <td>CARGUE-SKN-424</td>
                                        <td>DEVOLUCION-SKN-424</td>
                                        <td>CARGUE-SKX-282</td>
                                        <td>DEVOLUCION-SKX-282</td>
                                        <td>CARGUE-SKN-776</td>
                                        <td>DEVOLUCION-SKN-776</td>
                                        <td>INENTARIO TOTAL</td>
                                    </thead>



                                    <tr>
                                        <td>Semipura:</td>
                                        <td><input class="monto" type="number" name="semipura" id="semipura" placeholder="Semipura" onkeyup="sumar()">
                                        </td>
                                        <td><input class="monto" type="number" name="semipura_pr" id="semipura_pr" placeholder="Semipura" onkeyup="sumar()">
                                        </td>
                                        <td><input class="monto" type="number" name="semipura_c_424" id="semipura" placeholder="Semipura" onkeyup="sumar()">
                                        </td>
                                        <td><input class="monto" type="number" name="semipura_d_424" id="semipura" placeholder="Semipura" onkeyup="sumar()">
                                        </td>
                                        <td><input class="monto" type="number" name="semipura_c_282" id="semipura" placeholder="Semipura" onkeyup="sumar()">
                                        </td>
                                        <td><input class="monto" type="number" name="semipurad_d_282" id="semipura" placeholder="Semipura" onkeyup="sumar()">
                                        </td>
                                        <td><input class="monto" type="number" name="semipura_c_776" id="semipura" placeholder="Semipura" onkeyup="sumar()">
                                        </td>
                                        <td><input class="monto" type="number" name="semipura_d_776" id="semipura" placeholder="Semipura" onkeyup="sumar()">
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <span id="spTotal" name="spTotal" disabled></span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
```

Y este es mi `.php` para registrar los datos capturas en la base de datos.

```
//Inventario Total

    $fecha = $_POST["fecha"];
    $spTotal = $_POST["semipura"];
    
    
    $insertarinvTotal = "INSERT into  invtotal(fecha, semipura)
                        VALUES ('$fecha',$spTotal)";
```

En la tabla ingreso el numero que deseo y por medio de una funcion se suman y restan automaticamente, pero cuando quiero capturar los datos del total para ingresarlos a mi base de datos, me inserta el numero que ingrese en la primera fila. Como puedo capturar los datos del total para que me guarde el total y no la primera fila?

Answer (score 0):

No he terminado de entender tu explicación pero entiendo que `<span id="spTotal" name="spTotal" disabled></span>` muestra la suma de todos los valores de tu tabla cierto?
Podrías crear un `<input type="hidden" name="nombre de mi nuevo input" value="el valor de la suma">` y recoger por $POST el valor de ese `<input>`. Simplemente añádele el valor a este nuevo `<input>` en tu función `suma()` a continuación de introducirlo al `<span>`.
Una vez esto recoge el valor por POST: `$spTotal = $_POST["nombre de mi nuevo input"];`

Comment: Al momento que cambio mi span por un input de tipo hidden no me muestra los resultados de la suma como lo hacia anteriormente. Basicamente lo que quiero hacer es capturar los datos de esa suma y que me los guarde en mi base de datos.

Comment: No dije que cambies el span por un input hidden. Mantén tu span para poder mostrar el valor en tu web, pero además añade el input para poder enviar ese valor a través de POST.